# String Multiplication with Shapes (Python)

Tags: python, string, constants, multiplication, ascii-art

I have a question regarding stretching shapes by using a constant in python. I am very beginner so novice code would help me extremely.

For example lets just say I wanted to create a square as such:

```
_________
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
```

Its not perfect but you get the point. So what I would like to do from here is have a constant labeled at the top of my program called something like, "WIDTH" and so Whenever I set the width to a different number the square will either expand or shrink depending on what the constant is set at.

So WIDTH = 3 
or WIDTH = 5 ---> This one will be larger than the WIDTH at 3.

Can someone please demonstrate this with novice code, that would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So I guess you can't do ascii art so my drawing of a square may or may not appear to actually show but its just a simple 4x4 for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

In python, a string is a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). A sequence can be multiplied by an integer, yielding a sequence containing as many repetitions of the original sequence: try
`'abc' * 3`

> `'abcabcabc'`

This works for underscores and spaces just the same ...